# Why does getting input at runtime give me different output as compared to storing the same value in variable?

Tags: c++

Code 1:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
  int a = 7;
  std::cout<<++a*++a;
}
```

Output: 81

Code 2:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
  int a;
  std::cin>>a;
  std::cout<<++a*++a;
}
```

Input: 7

Output: 72

I tried using scanf() and printf() but they are also giving me different results. I compiled these on g++ 4.8.4 and DevC++ and both behave the same way. Although on [ideone](http://ideone.com/o5ZOq0) both give the same output 81.

Why am I getting different outputs just by getting the value as an input?

Comment: Welcome to the Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: @MikelF But the correct result is the first case. Even with optimization you must get 81 as result.

Comment: @MRB Undefined behaviour. There is no "correct" result.

Comment: @juanchopanza Can you explain in plain word why `++a*++a` is UB? `++a * a++` is UB because the order of evaluation of parameters is unspecified, and the result depend on whether `a++` or `++a` evaluate first.

Comment: @MRB See the duplicate. It isn't just that the order of evaluation is unspecified. There is also no sequence point, so the operations can disrupt each other. But I think some of this may change in C++17.